# facebook like button iframe with dynamic url printed in asp.net razor templates

Tags: asp.net, razor, umbraco, facebook-like

I have a asp.net website in the umbraco cms, there I can use razor templating to create some macros.
I want to integrate a facebook like button in the page,
this works ONLY when I paste the intire iframe in a razor macro and incorporate the macro on my masterpage.

Though, if I want to include some parameters,
and I take the iframe URL out of the code snippet to paste another parameter inside that url
it stops working.

However, after rendering both the iframe url is 100% identical.

Anyone got an idea on how I can make sure that the correct site url is in that Facebook iframe parameter can be changed? (depending on the hostname I bind in the umbraco cms)

Here is my razor code that does not work:

```
@{
  var currentLangPath = "www.newurl.com"; 
  var iframeSource = "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=207125959336150&amp;href=" + currentLangPath + "&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=110&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;font=arial&amp;height=21";      
  }

<a href="#visitFanpage"><img src="/images/facebook_logo.jpg" alt="Solex Facebook" /></a>
<p>Become part of the community, and feel free to share your experience.</p>
<div class="social">
  <iframe src="@iframeSource" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:25px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

Here is the content of a Razor file that does work:

```
<a href="#visitFanpage"><img src="/images/facebook_logo.jpg" alt="Solex Facebook" /></a>
<p>Become part of the community, and feel free to share your experience.</p>
<div class="social">
  <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=207125959336150&amp;href=www.newurl.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=110&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;font=arial&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:25px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
</div>
```

Note that both these Razor files have EXACTLY the same output, so I find it very weird that the dynamic URL one does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output isn't actually the same, the iframeSource variable gets HTML encoded and therefore an "&amp;" turns into:

`&amp;amp;`

You could do two things:

1. Remove "amp;" after each "&" in the iframeSource
2. Instead of @iframeSource, use @Html.Raw(iframeSource)

Comment: darn, should have looked in the actual source instead of taking the rendered url from firebug,  firebug already decoded the entities, so the urls seemed identical.

thanks for the tip, going to try right away